# How do I add custom tooltip to hPlot in rCharts

Tags: javascript, r, rcharts

I'm able to make a great hPlot using the following code:

```
h1<-hPlot(x = "MedianAge", 
      y = "AnnualPopulationGrowth", 
      data = df, 
      type = "bubble", 
      size="AdolescentFertilityRate", group = "continent")
h1$title(text='Median Age vs Annual Population Growth in 2010')
h1
```

However, I have a field in my data.frame df, called "Name", that I want to display. I tried adding the following line:

```
h1<-hPlot(x = "MedianAge", 
  y = "AnnualPopulationGrowth", 
  data = df, 
  type = "bubble", 
  size="AdolescentFertilityRate", group = "continent")
h1$title(text='Median Age vs Annual Population Growth in 2010')
h1
```

However that doesn't work. Variations on this line like:

```
h1$tooltip(formatter("#! function(d) {return d.Name} !#"))
```

also do not work. Any help getting the name of the country to pop up in the tooltip would be awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example:

```
library(rCharts)
# data
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10), s = rnorm(10), z = letters[1:10])

# create plot object
p <- hPlot(y ~ x, data = df, size = "s", type = "bubble")

# fix data format
p$params$series[[1]]$data <- toJSONArray(df, json = F)

# add tooltip formatter
p$tooltip(formatter = "#! function() {return(this.point.z);} !#")

# show
p
```

Comment: smart tweak. however it won't work if the z values are already used for the bubble sizes...

Comment: When I run the code all the bubbles are the same size. Not the case if  plotted after just first 2 lines of code

Comment: May be have you find a solution at this time but have you tried a trick like this .  \n 
`df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10), z = rnorm(10), feature = letters[1:10])  
p$params$series[[1]]$data <- toJSONArray(df, json = F)  
p$tooltip(formatter = "#! function() {return(this.point.feature);} !#")`